# MODX - getresource TV - submit as email

Tags: modx-revolution, formit

Wondering if something exists in MODx or custom snippet that could allow me to do the following:

I am using getresources to pull a list of my resources including some TV's attached to each resource.

I want to be able to add a button to each resource that upon pressing, an email is sent to the logged in user's email address containing some of the resource TV's.

Any ideas
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a couple of options,

- look up modMail in the rtfm.modx.com & you can craft an email using that

OR, probably easier;

- use the formit email hook & a group of hidden form fields to submit/send the form data to email.

refer back to the docs [or Bob's guides] to get the user's information [email]